# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo, MapActivity Android

Tags: android, mapactivity

I'm really new on Android Programming, I'm trying to follow some tutorial on internet about how to make google map driving direction on android. but somehow the code didn't work, although my eclipse didn't show any error on the code. anyone can help if something wrong in this code?

this is my MapDirectionActivity

```
    package my.map.direction;


    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    //import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URL;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

    //import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MapDirectionActivity extends MapActivity {


        MapView myMapView = null;
        MapController myMc = null;
        GeoPoint geoPoint = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            myMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            geoPoint = null;
            myMapView.setSatellite(false);

            String htw = "-6.3039,106.8267";
            String storkower = "-6.29436,106.8859";
            String pairs[] = getDirectionData(htw, storkower);
            String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(",");

            //starting point
            GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1])*1E6), (int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0])*1E6));

            myMc = myMapView.getController();
            geoPoint = startGP;
            myMc.setCenter(geoPoint);
            myMc.setZoom(14);
            myMapView.getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(startGP, startGP));

            GeoPoint gp1;
            GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;

            for(int i = 1; i<pairs.length;i++){
                lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
                gp1 = gp2;

                gp2 = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1])*1E6), (int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0])*1E6));
                myMapView.getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(gp1,gp2));
                Log.d("xxx","pair"+pairs[i]);
            }

            myMapView.getOverlays().add(new DirectionPathOverlay(gp2, gp2));
            myMapView.getController().animateTo(startGP);
            myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            myMapView.displayZoomControls(true);

        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
            return false;
        }


        private String[] getDirectionData(String srcPlace, String destPlace){
            String urlString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="
                    + srcPlace + "&daddr=" + destPlace
                    + "&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml";

        Log.d("URL",urlString); 

        Document doc = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        String pathContent = "";

        try{
            url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());     
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineString");
        for(int s=0; s< nl.getLength();s++){
            Node rootNode = nl.item(s);
            NodeList configItems = rootNode.getChildNodes();
            for(int x=0;x<configItems.getLength();x++){
                Node lineStringNode = configItems.item(x);
                NodeList path = lineStringNode.getChildNodes();
                pathContent = path.item(0).getNodeValue();
            }
        }

        String[] tempContent = pathContent.split(" ");
        return tempContent;
        }

    }
```

my DirectionPathOverlay

```
public class DirectionPathOverlay extends Overlay{

    private GeoPoint gp1;
    private GeoPoint gp2;

    public DirectionPathOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2){
        this.gp1 = gp1;
        this.gp2 = gp2;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when){

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        if(shadow == false){
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            Point point = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            Point point2 = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            canvas.drawLine((float) point.x, (float) point.y, (float) point2.x, (float) point2.y, paint);
        }
    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow){

        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }
}
```

and i got this following error on my logcat

```
05-02 08:51:09.972: I/dalvikvm(629): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 08:51:09.982: I/dalvikvm(629): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 08:51:10.062: D/URL(629): http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=52.458402,13.526616&daddr=52.523559,13.475826&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml
05-02 08:51:10.082: D/AndroidRuntime(629): Shutting down VM
05-02 08:51:10.102: W/dalvikvm(629): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.google.maps/my.google.maps.MapsTestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at my.google.maps.MapsTestActivity.getDirectionData(MapsTestActivity.java:100)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at my.google.maps.MapsTestActivity.onCreate(MapsTestActivity.java:38)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-02 08:51:10.122: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  ... 11 more
05-02 08:51:10.152: D/dalvikvm(629): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 5% free 5848K/6151K, paused 5ms+4ms
05-02 08:51:10.172: W/CursorWrapperInner(629): Cursor finalized without prior close()
05-02 08:51:10.172: W/CursorWrapperInner(629): Cursor finalized without prior close()
05-02 08:51:10.472: I/dalvikvm(629): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 08:51:10.482: I/dalvikvm(629): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 08:51:10.702: I/dalvikvm(629): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 08:51:10.702: I/dalvikvm(629): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 08:51:12.482: I/Process(629): Sending signal. PID: 629 SIG: 9
05-02 09:05:07.352: I/dalvikvm(647): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 09:05:07.372: I/dalvikvm(647): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 09:05:07.802: I/dalvikvm(647): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 09:05:07.832: I/dalvikvm(647): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 09:05:07.942: D/URL(647): http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=52.458402,13.526616&daddr=52.523559,13.475826&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml
05-02 09:05:07.972: D/AndroidRuntime(647): Shutting down VM
05-02 09:05:07.972: W/dalvikvm(647): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.google.maps/my.google.maps.MapsTestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at my.google.maps.MapsTestActivity.getDirectionData(MapsTestActivity.java:100)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at my.google.maps.MapsTestActivity.onCreate(MapsTestActivity.java:38)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  ... 11 more
05-02 09:05:08.032: D/dalvikvm(647): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 5% free 5848K/6151K, paused 4ms+7ms
05-02 09:05:08.032: W/CursorWrapperInner(647): Cursor finalized without prior close()
05-02 09:05:08.032: W/CursorWrapperInner(647): Cursor finalized without prior close()
05-02 09:05:08.302: I/dalvikvm(647): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 09:05:08.342: I/dalvikvm(647): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-02 09:05:08.632: I/dalvikvm(647): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-02 09:05:08.654: I/dalvikvm(647): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

i already check my main.xml and manifest.xml with any necessary setting to run google map, and i already test similiar setting for xml on my another mapactivity programm and it's work, so i dont think that my apikey didn't work

Comment: Something inside method getDirectionData starting at line 100 has a null reference. Put a breakpoint in this method and debug and step through it to find out what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the log you see:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 09:05:07.982: E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at my.google.maps.MapsTestActivity.getDirectionData(MapsTestActivity.java:100)

So the problem is the function getDirectionData that is returning a NULL.